# How do i access a GIT repository through VPN with XCode or Sourcetree (on a mac)

Tags: xcode, macos, git, atlassian-sourcetree

It should be simple, but i just cant get anything to work.

My Mac mini was connected to the office network (Windows server) and the repository is located on a server harddisk. I have a cloned working copy on the mac etc.

Now the Mac is sitting somewhere else and is connected to the server via VPN.
Because i dont know what exactly it does, let me describe what i was able to pull off.
In finder with cmd+k i entered "smb://192.168.xxx.xxx" and the finder did show the server. I can access the data and the repository.

I use sourcetree to access the git repository. In the bookmarks of sourcetree i can add it as a new repo and it says "This is a Git repository". Now when i hit "clone" it says "cloning from..." all fine... except, it never ends. Watched this for 10 minutes, no network traffic, no file appears on the harddrive. (waited longer... )

When i cancel this, the following line appears "Cloning into /Users/..." and "Completed with errors, see above" but there is no error above.

Now i opened the existing clone with sourcetree and attempted to change the repo location but i just dont know what to enter. It now starts with "/SomeFolder/..." and that folder still exists but now its behind the VPN. So what do i enter ? I tried some variations with IP etc but nothing worked and quite frankly im not getting along with my/a mac.

I really dont care about sourcetree, if its best to use plain XCode, so be it, but i need something that works.

**Update 1**

Im still having trouble.
The answers with the SSH require a username, which one ? 
A former colleague set up this mac for me. I have a VPN Username, a win-domain user and an apple id... which of the 3 is meant in ur SSH lines ?

It may sound trivial but, when i enter the git rep folder, do i have to end the line with a slash or not ?

In the local network the rep folder just started with "/Data/..." so if i put an IP before that, does the IP need a slash before it as well ? I mean, on windows i would know what to do and the only reason why i ask these silly questions is because none of it seems to work on the mac :/

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH,

you can do: git clone ssh://remote_username@ip.of.remote.machine/path/to/git_repository

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Xcode, but using key pairs. And when you do that in Xcode, you have to do a little bit of extra configuration: just paste your keys into the ones it put into the repository it made for you then presto (this is how you use GitHub or BitBucket with Xcode).

The source control stuff in Xcode 5 is pretty awesome actually.

http://www.elastichead.me/2013/01/github-and-xcode.html#.UpjarJGWyZY

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:
1) Open via Finder go to server, enter samba server data, leave that window open (it's the established connection to the server), then in XCode you can choose add repository inside the organizer (Cmd+Shift+2). or in XCode 5, it's under Preferences > Accounts, then plus button add repository
2) Another way would be to enable SSH access to the VPN Server, XCode supports SSH, just go into organizer, click "Add Repository", then enter in location field: ssh://remote_username@ip.of.remote.machine/path/to/git_repository
It will ask your for the password.

Comment: my Organizer doesnt have the "Add Repository" option

Comment: It's the under the plus button at the bottom of the left sidebar. Also you should switch at top bar to "Repositories".

Comment: i dont have "repositories" on top, just devices, projects and archives

Comment: Then you have XCode 5, it's under Preferences > Accounts, then plus button add repository. See updated answer

Comment: I still dont understand what i enter then

Comment: Try entering the samba address without the smb prefix, or try adding server that could also work if it is enabled on the remote server.